# Problems dealing with big dataframes in databricks notebook

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I am having problems dealing with a big dataframe in databricks notebook. This is the schema of my dataframe:

```
root
 |-- PAYMENT_DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PAYMENT_REFERENCE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ACCOUNT_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ROUTING_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FUND_AMT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BATCH_REFERENCE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BATCH_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CUSTOMER_BATCH_REFERENCE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CUSTOMER_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MERCHANT_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EXTERNAL_MID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- STORE_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CHAIN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BATCH_AMT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AMOUNT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CARD_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CHARGE_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CHARGE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CARD_PLAN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CARD_NO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TRANSACTION_DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SETTLEMENT_DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- AUTHORIZATION_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CHARGEBACK_CONTROL_NO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ROC_TEXT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TRN_ACI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LIFE_CYCLE_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CARD_SCHEME_REF: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TRN_REF_NUM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SETTLEMENT_METHOD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CURRENCY_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CB_ACQ_REF_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CHGBK_RSN_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CHGBK_RSN_DESC: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MER_REF: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CUST_COD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TRN_ARN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TERM_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ENT_NUM: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ingestionDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _rescued_data: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source_metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- file_path: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- file_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- file_size: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- file_block_start: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- file_block_length: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- file_modification_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |--  PAYMENT_DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  ACCOUNT_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |--  ROUTING_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUND_AMT: string (nullable = true)
 |--  BATCH_REFERENCE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  BATCH_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CUSTOMER_BATCH_REFERENCE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CUSTOMER_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |--  MERCHANT_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |--  EXTERNAL_MID: string (nullable = true)
 |--  STORE_NUMBER: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CHAIN: string (nullable = true)
 |--  BATCH_AMT: string (nullable = true)
 |--  AMOUNT: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CARD_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CHARGE_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CHARGE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CARD_PLAN: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CARD_NO: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRANSACTION_DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTLEMENT_DATE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  AUTHORIZATION_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CHARGEBACK_CONTROL_NO: string (nullable = true)
 |--  ROC_TEXT: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRN_ACI: string (nullable = true)
 |--  LIFE_CYCLE_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CARD_SCHEME_REF: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRN_REF_NUM: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTLEMENT_METHOD: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CURRENCY_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CB_ACQ_REF_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CHGBK_RSN_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CHGBK_RSN_DESC: string (nullable = true)
 |--  MER_REF: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CUST_COD: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRN_ARN: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TERM_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |--  ENT_NUM: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SURCHG_AMOUNT: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CONVNCE_AMT: string (nullable = true)
 |--  PURCH_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CHK_NUM: string (nullable = true)
 |--  ISS_CCT_COD: string (nullable = true)
 |--  POS_ENT_MODE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CH_ID_METH: string (nullable = true)
 |--  MOTO_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CAT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  CVV2_RESULT: string (nullable = true)
 |--  DR_SERVICE_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TDSXT_TRN_DWNGRD: string (nullable = true)
 |--  AUTH_FAIL_APPROVAL_CDE_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  AUTH_FAIL_AUTH_RESP_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  AUTH_FAIL_TRN_ID_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  AUTH_FAIL_AUTH_DTE_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  AUTH_FAIL_TRN_ACI_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  AUTH_FAIL_TRK_DATA_COND_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_TIMELINESS_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_AVS_RESP_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_CVV_RESP_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_TAX_INCL_FLG_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_TAX_AMT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_CUST_CDE_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_AUTH2SETTL_AMT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_INVC_NUM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_CUST_SVC_NUM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  SETTL_FAIL_POS_ENTRY_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_CUST_REF_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_RENTER_NAM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_RETURN_CITY_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_RETURN_ST_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_RETURN_CTRY_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_RETURN_LOC_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_CKOUT_RETURN_DTE_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_CUST_SVC_NUM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_PROP_PHN_NUM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_MKT_SPECFC_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  RENT_FAIL_CK_IN_OUT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_PASSGR_NAM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_DEPART_DTE_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_ORIG_CITY_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_LEG1_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_RESTR_TIC_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_MULT_SEQ_NUM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_MULT_SEQ_CNT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_ANCIL_TKT_NUM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_ANCIL_SVC_CAT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_ANCIL_CONN_TKT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  TRVL_FAIL_ANCIL_PASSGR_DAT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_PURCH_TYP_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_FUEL_TYP_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_UNIT_MEAS_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_FUEL_QTY_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_PRICE_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_TAX_EXEMPT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_COMPANY_NAM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_PURCH_TIM_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_QTY_EXPONENT_IND: string (nullable = true)
 |--  FUEL_FAIL_SLS_AMT_IND: string (nullable = true)
```

it contains 65 million records however I loaded only 100 into databricks notebook in order to test a cleansing method on the data
this is the method I am using:

```
# Define the characters you want to remove
characters_to_remove = ['=', '"', '$']

# Remove specified characters from all columns
for char in characters_to_remove:
    for column in df.columns:
        if column != 'source_metadata':
            df = df.withColumn(column, regexp_replace(col(column), char, ''))
```

however I am getting error when displaying df:

```
grpc_shaded.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message had too many levels of nesting.  May be malicious.  Use CodedInputStream.setRecursionLimit() to increase the depth limit.
```

I would like to know how to deal with such dataframes in databricks notebook, in silver layer, in an efficient way. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed that when I am having the error when using ```display(df)```, but not when using ```df.show()```, but the latter is not a good practice